# print stdoutput using python behave

Tags: python, testing, bdd, python-behave

I want behave to output all print-statements - e.g. for commandline debugging.

By default behave captures all std-output and prints only on fails.

```
@when('we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
     print ('please debug me')
     assert True is not False
```

Answer (score 0):

use:
`behave -f plain --no-capture`